# Why does the getValidStr method turn into an infinite loop?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ValidateMe {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int c;
    String d;

    Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);

    c = getValidIntScore(scnr);
    d = getValidStrName(scnr);
}
public static int getValidIntScore(Scanner scnr){
    int c;

    System.out.println("Enter an integer test score between 0-100 inclusive:");
    c = scnr.nextInt();

    while (c < 0 || c > 100) {
        System.out.println("Test score must be a value between 0-100 inclusive. Enter the test score:");
        c = scnr.nextInt();
    }
    return c;
}

public static String getValidStrName(Scanner scnr){
    String c;

    System.out.println("Enter student's full name:");
    c = scnr.nextLine();

    while (c.isEmpty()){
        System.out.println("Name must be non-empty and non-blank. Enter the student's full name:");
    }
    return c;
}
}
```

When I run this, I can get the test score just fine, but when I get to the student's name, I cannot even enter input and it keeps running over and over... How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 problems in this;

### mixing nextX and nextLine without setting delimiter

You can't mix `nextLine` and `next(anything else)` without things going rather wrong. It sounds like you want one enter to be equal to one input. That's easily done:

Update the scanner to tell it that you want it to scan for newlines, not whitespace. After making the scanner (`new Scanner`), immediately run:

`scanner.useDelimiter("\r?\n");`

Which tells it that input is separated by newlines (enter presses). All other solutions (such as throwing `nextLine()` calls in to 'reset' it) result in issues if the user enters space-separated things when you ask for non-full-line inputs (even though it is extremely common advice here on SO, the delimiter thing is simpler and doesn't fail in such cases).

### Not re-reading in the loop

Computer does as it is told.

You are asking it: Hey, as long as `c` is empty, do the following: print that c is not empty.

So, it'll just spam that line over and over. c is empty and will remain empty forever, which is why it does that. You'd have to update c inside that while block at the end there, e.g. with `c = scanner.nextLine();`.

Comment: I have posted a answer same to you,but do not know why got a downvote